# Chrome extension for "Open this URI with …"

Tags: chrome

In Opera < 12.x it was possible to open the current website with a different browser. It detected which browsers are installed and added it to the context menu of the browser as you can see in the attached screenshot:

[image: Open Link with …]

There is also a Firefox add-on called [Browser View](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/browser-view-plus/) with the same function.

This was a very nice feature and I really wan't this for Google Chrome too. Does anyone know an extension like this?

Comment: Does something similar exist for Firefox? Browser View is no longer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing. At work I have to use different browsers for different websites.

I wrote a chrome extension that adds exactly what you're looking for, you can add whatever browser you have installed on your computer and right click to open the current url in another browser. You can also add specific URLs to automatically open in another browser.

[Open in Second Browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/second-browser/camgemdhfmfogamncjkgddnloggffmbc)

Comment: This link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 4):

There are two extensions:

**Open with external application** by Lorenz Cuno Klopfenstein

> Opens any link of a webpage with a custom external application.
>
> "Open with external application" (in dire need of a better name) is an extension for the Google Chrome web browser. It allows the user to select any executable and use links of the web pages s/he is browsing as a command line parameter when launching such executable.
>
> The user might, for instance, decide to open a target link in Firefox, Opera, Safari or any other application capable of handling an URL parameter.

Get it here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-with-external-applic/hccmhjmmfdfncbfpogafcbpaebclgjcp

If you prefer Firefox there is **Open With Firefox** by bnk

Get it here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-with-firefox/jmjejjdalfogiopknpabihjhplfkjjjk

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. It seems that _Open with external application_ can only handle one application so it's not really what I need.

Comment: Neither of these work for me with the latest Chrome. Nothing appears in the right-click menu at all. I don't think it's another extension that's messing it up. Anyone experiencing this? Any ideas?!

Comment: @SilverSideDown You need to enable NPAPI in chrome://flags. It is disabled by default in Chrome now (that's why the extension appears not to work), and NPAPI will be completely removed from Chrome in version 45. I mostly left Chrome for this very reason of Google restricting Chrome into an even tighter sandbox that Google thinks is best for everyone - closed proprietary standards unlike Firefox which is open to customization. Unfortunately, I use WhatsApp Web and it can only run smoothly and as an app in Chrome.

Comment: Well that certainly explains things. At least this gives me a workaround until Sept. That's a huge bummer, as this is a very useful extension. I scanned the alternate technologies they recommend in http://g.co/npapi and I don't see anything that could help here to migrate.

Comment: NPAPI is gone. This solution also.

Comment: From Chrome 51, NPAPI gone, this solution too :(

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote this extension CopyTabs as, the others weren't working for me. 
Get it here:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copytabs/obkbjogekcjalnaebheboejhfkamadkg