# Is there a "Open in Firefox" Google Chrome extension?

Tags: osx, chrome, firefox

**Question**

Is there a "Open in Firefox" Google Chrome extension for Google Chrome on Mac OS X?

**Research**

- "[Open in Chrome](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-chrome/)" is a Firefox addon; I'm looking for an extension that goes the other way
- There is "[Open In Firefox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-with-firefox/jmjejjdalfogiopknpabihjhplfkjjjk/related)" but it doesn't work on OS X
- The "[Open with external application](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-with-external-applic/hccmhjmmfdfncbfpogafcbpaebclgjcp/related)" extension from [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3532) doesn't seem to work on OS X
- I've googled for "[open in firefox chrome extension](https://www.google.ch/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=open%20in%20firefox%20chrome%20extension)" but found nothing
- I've searched in the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps) but found nothing
- I've found the "[Google Chrome plugin/bookmarklet: “open in Firefox”?](https://superuser.com/questions/89449/google-chrome-plugin-bookmarklet-open-in-firefox)" question on Superuser.com but that answer is for Windows, I'm on Mac OS X

**Versions**

- Google Chrome Version 38.0.2125.122
- Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question, I've never found an OSX app to do this, so I've used the following Applescript (edited to work for Firefox, instead of Safari):

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set urlChrome to get URL of active tab of first window
end tell

tell application "Firefox"
    open location urlChrome
end tell
```

Pretty simple - get current tab in Chrome's URL and open it it Firefox. Tested on Yosemite.

To make:

1. Open (apple)Script Editor from Spotlight or Launchpad
2. Copy and paste above code
3. Save as File Format: Application
4. Drag to dock for easy access
5. (optional) Set up a shortcut for the 'app': System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > + > Find the app > Set the shortcut:

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Impressive solution.

Comment: @Lernkurve Thanks - hopefully, you'll find a better way soon!

Answer (score 2):

Don't have OSX and seldom use Chrome so don't know if this page would help you, it describes both directions between Firefox and Chrome. (sorry, low points does not permit posting as a lesser comment)
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/transfer-open-tabs-from-firefox-to-chrome

Answer (score 0):

I posted this answer on another question here [Chrome extension for "Open this URI with …"](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/chrome-extension-for-open-this-uri-with?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I wrote a chrome extension that allows you to open the current url in other browsers, which includes firefox. You can add whatever browser you have installed on your computer, and also set specific URLs to automatically launch.

Extension link is here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/second-browser/camgemdhfmfogamncjkgddnloggffmbc

Costs 99 cents